# C# get the first named group that matches in a regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have N patterns that I want to match with one single regex, each pattern has an individual regex. What I'm doing right now is joining each regex with the '|' operator and giving each individual regex a group name.

In the example below I'm looking to get the matched group (Stream, Triple or Double) without having to iterate through all the groups in the match. Is this possible ?

```
/* language=regex */
@"(?<Stream>((C[b-i][0-3][5-9]){7,}(C[b-i][0-3].)?)+)" + 
 "|(?<Triple>(Ca[0-4].)(Ca[0-4].)(C...))" +
 "|(?<Double>(Ca[0-4].)(C...))",
```

Comment: `Regex.Match()` returns a `Match` which can allow you to access named groups. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=net-5.0 and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match

Comment: `match.Groups[0]` where match is [Match object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups?view=net-5.0)

Comment: match.Groups[0] returns the group of the whole regex not the first named group

Comment: It is as easy as `match.Groups["Stream"].Value`, etc.

Comment: well thats the thing I don't know which pattern I match, u are assuming I know that I will match a Stream but only one of these pattern will match